# Allow flagging of link-only answers when reviewing first posts

Tags: feature-request, flags, link-only-answers, first-post-review

Can the flagging options on first posts be modified, so people with the close-votes privilege can cast a close vote?

When reviewing first posts, I cannot flag link-only answers as link-only. The options offered are as follows, but none is ideal:

[image: First post flagging reasons]

If I saw the same question in the close-votes review queue, I could directly flag it as link-only. But here in the first-posts review queue, I can only flag with a wrong reason or give more work to the overloaded moderators by flagging as "other".

The only option I see involves me in more work: I could open the question and then click the "close" link on that answer. But I cannot vote to close from the first-posts review.

Comment: In the close review queue you cannot flag a post as link only *either*. For posts that are just links you'd use *Not an answer*.

Comment: And you cannot close answers. You can only close questions, and the correct procedure is to just open the question using the supplied link.

Comment: At the risk of a lenghty discussion: that [answer is not link only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)...